# How to I get the path to a file with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am currently using Django's forms to create a `FileField` that allows the user to upload a file. However, after I select the file, it creates an object of type `django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile`, which is a copy of the original file.

How would I go about to get the original path of this file so I can either modify or replace it?

```
# forms.py

class UploadFile(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(label="Select File: ", required=True)
```

```
# views.py

def get_path(response):
    context = {}

    if response.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFile(response.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            file = form.cleaned_data["file"]
            # Is there a  way to get the original file path or should I just not use FileField?
            print("The File Path Here")
```

Comment: Just save the file now where you like with the name you like. There is no "original" path now because the file is not yet saved.

Comment: @Marco how can I get the path of that "original" file that was uploaded then? I would like to replace the "original" file that was uploaded, which requires the path of the original file, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

temporary_file_path function

```
if form.is_valid():
    file = form.cleaned_data["file"]
    print(file.temporary_file_path())
```

Comment: I am getting this error 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'temporary_file_path'

Comment: How big is the file you are uploading?

Comment: its about 11.3KB, not a big file

Comment: ok, with small files, below the theshold (2mb) is not stored as a temp file, but in memory, so this function wont work, and I havent work with files in memory, but you can check this blogpost about it https://newbedev.com/python-and-django-how-to-use-in-memory-and-temporary-files

Comment: thanks for that link, by modifying the maximum file size I am able to change it to use the temporary file and I can use your solution, but now I am back to the same problem. I still need the original file path in order to move this modified file to replace the uploaded file. Is there a way I can get that original path instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to try modifying an `InMemoryUploadedFile` file path. However, just keep in mind the term "*InMemory*".

The file has not been saved as yet, so there will be no path associated with the file before saving. To my knowledge (*I stand corrected if I'm wrong here*), `InMemoryUploadedFile` do not have a path attribute either, but content/file, a filename, etc.; in which the filename can be modified. You can see the [doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/#InMemoryUploadedFile).

You could make modifications to the filename though if you wish by doing the following:

```
if form.is_valid():
     form.cleaned_data["file"].name = "modify.txt"  # or to whatever filename and extension you want.
     form.save()  # If you have a save method defined
```

However, you could get a little creative in saving the file to a specific path within the media folder though. For example:

```
# forms.py

import os
from django.conf import settings

class UploadFile(forms.Form):
     file = forms.FileField(label="Select File: ", required=True)

     # The save method that will save the file to a specific location in the media folder.
     def save(self):  
          filename = file.name
          folder = 'uploaded/'
    
          # Create the folder if it doesn't exist.
          try:
               os.mkdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, folder))
          except:
               pass

          # Save the uploaded file inside that folder.
          file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, folder, filename)
    
          with open(file_path, 'wb+') as destination:  
               for chunk in file.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)

# view.py

def get_path(response):
     if response.method == "POST":
          form = UploadFile(response.FILES)

          if form.is_valid():
               file = form.cleaned_data["file"]
               # file.name = "modify.txt"  # Can modify here if necessary...
               
               form.save()
```